# running a cron job every 12hrs

Tags: tabs, cron

Please I need help running a cron job every 01:00 AM. The format I currently have sends mail 12:00  but it keeps looping itself every minute, any help will be appreciated.
Here is my current format

```
0 */12 * * *
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need every to run it every 12 hours or every 24 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyday 1am should be like the following

```
00 1 * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
0 1 * * * cmd
```

to run at 1am

Answer (score 0):

Every single day at 01.00 AM :

```
0 0 1 1/1 * ? *
```